# Override core data setter method for to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, overriding, getter-setter

I override many setters for my core data structures to keep much of the "business logic" in the database. What is the best way to override the setter methods for a to-many relationship within core data? It seems that the setter functions, for an relationship called 'Things,' include:

```
- (void)addThingsObject:(Thing *)value;
- (void)removeThingsObject:(Thing *)value;
- (void)addThings:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeThings:(NSSet *)value;
```

Do I need to override all four of these functions? What is the best practice for how to do this cleanly? If there is an inverse relationship, do I need to do anything within the setters to make sure that the inverse is set properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MoGenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator).  It creates two classes for each entity in core data, one of which you use to write custom code to manage the entity.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, overriding the methods xCode creates for you kind of limits your possibilities. It's much more maintainable to create a category **for each of the classes you need to add methods to** and add only the methods you're interested in. Like, if you want to replace an object, add a `replaceThingObject:(Thing*)obj1 withThingObject(Thing*)obj2` method in the category. Same goes with add or remove, not just replace. Implementing them all just to follow up xCode generated code would be crazy if you don't need them...